# Can't include Coin-or Rehearse Library to my own code

Tags: c++, coin-or

I download the Coin-or Rehearse Library, and I follow the steps present in the tutorial.
I successfully "make install" and "make test", which both seem like providing the right output.

But now I want to include this solver into my own code, which means I have another cpp file and I want to include the solver just like the example test cpp Rehearse provides.

I copy the whole Rehearse file into /usr/local/include , but it doesn't work.(error : .h files not found)

Also , if I replace every appearance of "testRehearse.cpp" in Makefile.am by my own cpp name and run "make test", it can successfully be compiled but this is not I want.(I prefer compiling my code by using g++)

Backgroung : running on OSX

Comment: I recommend adding the build instructions you are using to compile your code along with any build scripts used.

Comment: Well , I just follow the steps Rehearse official website provide.

Comment: After downloading all the files, I correctly install the solver library and the test program works well though.